# Problem pass array argument in mutation in apollo-graphql

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to create a mutation in graphql where I want to pass an arrangement of objects as an argument and I am presenting a problem in react with apollo-client. The error is as follows: Error !: Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Below I show the scheme and the mutation:

```
type Venta {
  _id: String!
  _idCliente: String
 clienteFinal: String
 total: Int!
 pago: Int!
 vuelto: Int!
 numeroFactura: Int!
 listadoProductos: [ProductoVendido]
   }
type ProductoVendido{
  nombre: String
  precio: Int
  cantidad: Int
}

type Mutation {
  createventa(listadoProductos: [ProductoVendido!]!): Venta!
  }
```

My expectation is to be able to pass an array of objects that in this case would be products of a shopping cart that comes from the react client. But my React application is breaking with the error: Error!: Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Comment: I found a solution to my question. And I will post the code based on the previous code so that if someone is going through my same problem I have an example code.

Basically you have to declare the input type to be able to pass more complex data types as an argument for the mutation.

Code:

    input inputProductoVendido {
     nombre: String
     precio: Int
     cantidad: Int
    }
    type ProductoVendido{
    nombre: String
    precio: Int
    cantidad: Int
    }
    createventa(venta: inputVenta, productos: [inputProductoVendido]): Venta